# Run a function across columns without stripping Labelled attributes

Tags: r, sapply, r-haven

I have a large number of SPSS files, and I need to generate random data that looks like the data that is in the file.

When I read in the SPSS files (using `haven`'s `read_sav`), they come in with variable and value labels (from labelled), and I would like each variable to have those same attributes when I write the SPSS file after scrambling the data. However, when I scramble the sequence of each column independently, `sapply` strips the Labelled attributes (because it's returning a matrix that I'm coercing into a `data.frame`).

How can I do this without stripping those attributes? See example below:

```
dat<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),b=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"))

var_label(dat$a)<-"The first variable"
val_labels(dat$a)<-c(first=1,
                     second=2,
                     third=3,
                     fourth=4,
                     fifth=5,
                     sixth=6,
                     seventh=7,
                     eighth=8,
                     ninth=9,
                     tenth=10)

var_label(dat$b)<-"The second variable"

# Variable has variable and value labels
dat$a

faker<-function(thing){
  thing<-sample(thing,length(thing),replace=TRUE)
  thing
}

rat<-as.data.frame(sapply(dat,faker))

# Variable no longer has variable and value labels
rat$a
```

edited to correct a typo on the last line of the code, which was dat$a and should have been rat$a

Comment: I can't reproduce it, but I wonder if it's because you reassign into `rat` and not over the original data `dat`. Is that real? If you intend to store into `rat`, then with R-4.1.2 and labelled-2.9.0, I still se labels after the calls to faker.

Comment: Edited to correct the typo pointed out by @r2evans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Up front, I'm assuming your reassignment to `rat` should really be `dat`, otherwise it is not reproducible and *shouldn't be* since `dat` is not changed when forming `rat`.)

Your use of `sapply` is homogenizing and dumbing-down the data, switch to `lapply`.

```r
# ...
dat<-as.data.frame(sapply(dat,faker))
dat$a
#  [1] "1"  "7"  "5"  "7"  "10" "2"  "1"  "4"  "9"  "4"
```

The fix,

```r
dat <- as.data.frame(lapply(dat,faker))
dat$a
# <labelled<double>[10]>: The first variable
#  [1]  2  3  8  9  8  5  5 10  1  3
# Labels:
#  value   label
#      1   first
#      2  second
#      3   third
#      4  fourth
#      5   fifth
#      6   sixth
#      7 seventh
#      8  eighth
#      9   ninth
#     10   tenth
```

Side note: when applying something to all columns of a frame, instead of `dat <- as.data.frame(lapply(...))`, I tend to use `dat[] <- lapply(...)`, as it preserves the frame's attributes and replaces/augments the columns' contents.

```r
# ...
dat[] <- lapply(dat, faker)
dat$a
# <labelled<double>[10]>: The first variable
#  [1] 4 8 7 7 9 7 9 1 3 5
# Labels:
#  value   label
#      1   first
#      2  second
#      3   third
#      4  fourth
#      5   fifth
#      6   sixth
#      7 seventh
#      8  eighth
#      9   ninth
#     10   tenth
```